# htc desire z root shell

Tags: rooting, htc-desire-z

I'm trying only to get a root shell, not persistent, don't want to flash any kind of image or install closed/proprietary apk, nor run scripts/exploits that write/erase/modify any flash.

For a newer device has been just a matter of few mins, found an exploit, compiled, pushed, executed, got the root shell, instead this one seem to be unbreakable, already spent hours trying different *approaches* :-|

`2.6.35.10-g53a84f9 (htc-kernel@and18-2) - Android/2.3.3`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[zergRush](https://github.com/revolutionary/zergRush) did it, seems to be the only one working, I just did some *personal* change to not remount `/data` and not set any property but just `chmod` an `adb` *pre-pushed* `/data/local/tmp/su`.